# Creating a LINQ to SQL compatible expression that accesses a property by its name

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, linq-to-sql

I was wondering if any of you has an idea on how to tackle this problem.

Suppose there's the following class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Description {get; set;}
    //...
}
```

I'd like to create an expression that can be passed in to LINQ's `Where` method in LINQ's `Where` method in LINQ to SQL, such as the following:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> expression = x => x.Description.Contains("foo");
```

The real problem here is that I don't know what field is going to be checked until runtime. The name of the property is provided as a string (in this case it would be "Description", but it can be "Description2", or any other property of the `Person` class). I can't use reflection directly in the expression itself to get the property value (by using `GetType`, `GetProperty` etc.) because the expression won't work when passed to `Where` in LINQ to SQL because it can't be translated to an SQL code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this minimal example, the desired property will be accessed and compared with another string, resulting in a boolean:

```
// GET: People
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var propertyName = "Description";
    var compareString = "abc";

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person));
    var memberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(Person).GetProperty(propertyName));
    var compare = Expression.Constant(compareString);
    var contains = Expression.Call(memberAccess, typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Contains), new[] { typeof(string) }), compare);
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(contains, new[] { parameter });

    return View(db.People.Where(expr).ToList());
}
```

Of course this is missing all checks, possible options, cache, ... The point is, you have to create the expression by yourself if you have to rely on runtime known types.